# How can I get Google Apps script html service to display data- attributes using :after?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, pseudo-element, google-caja

I have a simple apps-script that uses the html service and I need the :after pseudo-selector .

Boiling down the issue to a line of code, I have

```
<style>
test:after {
  content: attr(data-hidden);
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
}
</style>

<test data-hidden="Now you don't">Now you see me </test>
```

Per jsfiddle, the expected output would be "Now you see me **Now you don't**", but I only get "Now you see me"

If I remove the :after I get **Now you see me**, as expected.

FWIW I am using .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE)

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The `content: attr()` line is being stripped by the caja compiler. Try your code snippet on the [Caja Playground](http://caja.appspot.com/), and inspect the Rendered Result, which should be a better representation of how HTML will be sanitized when served from Google Apps Script than you'll get at jsfiddle.

Here's what is rendered:

```
<caja-v-html>
  <caja-v-head>
    <style>
      .CajaGadget2___ caja-v-test:after{
        display:inline-block;
        font-weight:bold;}
    </style>
  </caja-v-head>
  <caja-v-body>
    <caja-v-test data-caja-data-hidden="Now you don't">Now you see me </caja-v-test>
  </caja-v-body>
</caja-v-html>
```

The `data-hidden` attribute of the `<test>` tag survives, but there's no `content` attribute in the style to contain it. That's probably because the `attr()` statement appears to be an attack vector. ([example](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/CssAllowsArbitraryCodeExecution))

If we try again with a constant `content`, it survives cajoling:

```
<caja-v-html>
  <caja-v-head>
    <style>
      .CajaGadget2___ caja-v-test:after{
        content:"waffles";           <<<<<<
        display:inline-block;
        font-weight:bold;}
    </style>
  </caja-v-head>
  <caja-v-body>
    <caja-v-test data-caja-data-hidden="Now you don't">Now you see me </caja-v-test>
  </caja-v-body>
</caja-v-html>
```

Because of the sanitization, you're not going to be able to make `attr()` work this way. You could enter an issue on the [Caja Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/issues/list).

Comment: Indeed, it seems that attr is rejected per this [code review] (https://codereview.appspot.com/7308092/diff/6002/src/com/google/caja/lang/css/css-extensions-defs.json#newcode169)

"Reject attr(<identifier>) because it circumvents Domado attribute value
      virtualizations",
kpreid2 2013/02/13 20:26:59
This is in principle statically determinable in some cases (though it would need
context from the selector). Agreed we don't need it now, though.
ihab.awad 2013/02/13 22:20:30 Done.

That's a shame since I wanted to

Comment: use this to implement a responsive table using (http://codepen.io/geoffyuen/pen/FCBEg)